# using for loops to create variables with different names

Tags: python, variables, naming

I am trying to use a for loop to create 5 (currently) variables. I want to make these variables be named soldier+i, where i is the number iterated in the for loop.

```
    first_names=['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
    last_names=['Lname1', 'Lname2', 'Lname3', 'Lname4', 'Lname5']
    nick_names=['1','2','3','4','5']
    soldier_HPs=[10,9,8,7,6]
    for i in range(5):
        soldier+i=[first_names[i-1],last_names[i-1],nick_names[i-1],soldierHPs[i-1]]
```

As you can see, I want to store each soldier by naming the soldier "soldier+(respective number)". Then store its health, first, last, and nick names all as part of a list. The issue i am having is that it cannot concantenate strings and integers. the issue is that this is supposed to be the name of the variable. If I only wanted this to be a string to set a variable to, i could just use: x="soldier" + str(i). But again since this is the name of a variable, this will not work.

Comment: Have you learned about arrays?

Comment: They are lists in Python, not arrays.  You should still use them, though.

Comment: Yes i have learned about arrays. I am actually using arrays right now to store the location of the soldiers as well as high and low cover. I had not thought about using arrays to store the data where each y would represent a soldier and each y a different characteristic. I will probably ask my engineering teacher what he thinks is best. Again thank you for your help and if you have any more ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! I notice your profile as a high school student, so I won't assume any prior knowledge from you. Let's get to your questions then.

You are using `list`s in Python to store information about soldiers. And then you want to store information for each soldier, separately. Now, isn't that quite redundant?

If I want the first name of the first soldier, I can simply go for `first_name[0]`. All information is accessible in the current scope through meaningful variable names (i.e. first_names, last_names etc). If you put them in a list, you have to remember the first index is `first_names`, second is `last_names`, etc. These add another layer of confusion as your program/game code grows larger.

However, in some cases it is indeed more convenient to group information about the characters for purpose of iterations. In Python there is module called `collections`, where you can find a function called `namedtuple`. This function is a so called `factory function`, whose sole purpose is to declare and define class for you.

Say I want to define a `Soldier` class quickly, here is how

```
from collections import namedtuple

Soldier = namedtuple('Soldier', ['first_name', 'last_name', 'nick_name', 'HP'])
soldier_info = [ # this is list comprehension
    Soldier(first_names[idx], last_names[idx], nick_names[idx], soldier_hps[idx])
    for idx in range(len(first_names))
]
```

Then you can do

```
firstname_second_soldier = soldier_info[1].first_name
```

`namedtuple` is immutable and hashable like `tuple`, but with named fields.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now that you explain it, the way i have a list containing each bit of data, plus lists for each soldiers is very redundant. I do not particularly wish to use new modules currently. Though i will remember this module and will reference your comment in the future to do so. Currently I wish to push the boundaries of the built in functions as well as Tkinter, before looking into these other modules, to help me build my base of python so that new modules will be easier for me to use and comprehend in the future. If i have questions about this module I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
first_names=['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
last_names=['Lname1', 'Lname2', 'Lname3', 'Lname4', 'Lname5']
nick_names=['1','2','3','4','5']
soldier_HPs=[10,9,8,7,6]
soldiers = {}
for i in range(5):
    soldiers['soldier' + str(i-1)] = (first_names[i-1],last_names[i-1],nick_names[i-1],soldier_HPs[i-1])
```

Soldiers will then have the value

```
{'soldier2': ('name3', 'Lname3', '3', 8), 'soldier3': ('name4', 'Lname4', '4', 7), 'soldier0': ('name1', 'Lname1', '1', 10), 'soldier1': ('name2', 'Lname2', '2', 9), 'soldier-1': ('name5', 'Lname5', '5', 6)}
```

Comment: Why not just `[ ['name1', 'Lname1', '1', 10], ..., ['name5', Lname5', '5', 6] ]`, and let the canonical indices be key? Is it necessary to use string keys?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little too advanced for you right now, but I think it's good to understand the concepts of object oriented programming and get introduced to them as soon as possible.  A possible solution for this would be the creation of a Soldier `class`, like so:

```
class Soldier(object):

    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,nickname,hp):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.hp = hp

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.nickname)


soldier_one = Soldier('name1','lname1','1',10)

print soldier_one ## 1
print soldier_one.first_name ## name1
print soldier_one.hp ## 10

soldier_two = Soldier('name2','lname2','2',9)
```

and so on.  Let me know if you have any questions about this approach - it's a little less intuitive at first, but I seriously wished that I had taken it more seriously when I started off in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have heard of classes before but i don't think I have ever used them. looking through your code, i understand it and i think i would be able to use it fairly well in my code. Out of the responses I have gotten, I plan to use your solution since i agree that the earlier I learn about classes the better. My first question is the second function you define under soldier "__repr__(self): Can you explain why this part is needed? I have worked on my code since, and if you would like me to send you the full version so you can see the whole code let me know.

Comment: @SWMC Yeah, I should have included a little bit more about that.  Defining a `__repr__(self)` method in a class isn't necessary - but doing so basically tells the Python interpreter that "every time you're told to refer to this class, use this *representation* of it (that's what `__repr__` stands for.) So, if I hadn't defined the `__repr__` method, on the line that says `print soldier_one`, instead of 1 it would have printed `<__main__.Soldier object at 0x0189A510>`. but because I told the `__repr__` method to return Soldier's nicknames if that call is ever made, it instead prints `1`.